# Angular custom focus directive not working on ion-item (but does work on the native <input/>)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, OnDestroy, Optional} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appFocus]',
})
export class AppFocusDirective implements OnChanges {
    @Input() appFocus: boolean = false;
    @Input() focusDelay: number = 0;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}
    ngAfterViewChecked(){
      this.checkFocus();
    }

    private checkFocus() {
        if (this.appFocus && document.activeElement !== this.elementRef.nativeElement) {
            let checkFocusTimeoutHandle: number;
            const focus = () => {
                this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
            };
            checkFocusTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(focus, this.focusDelay) as any;
        }
    }
}
```

Its purpose is to set focus on an element when the view has been initialized. I am building my app with ionic and I need this effect for ion-input component, but it does not seem to work. However, when I use this directive on the native input element, it does work.

```
  <!--doesn't get focused (when uncommented)-->
  <!--<ion-input [appFocus]="true" ></ion-input>-->
  <!--does get focused-->
  <input [appFocus]="true" />
```

What do I have to change to make this work for ion-item?

Here is a [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-hnz842?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) with the demo. For the focus() effect to work, the stackblitz app has to be viewed through its [**DIRECT LINK**](https://ionic-hnz842.stackblitz.io/).

Comment: stackblitz is working!

Comment: The native input works. If you comment out the native input and uncomment ion-input - you see the problem.

Comment: what you want to achieve will not work on iOS devices - Apple's stance is that only user should "create" focus. At least in modern iOS safari (after 10,3 or so) it is now not triggerable via js

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do programettically use template ref to set ion-item focus or use ViewChild to get ref from the dom

**HTML**

```
 <ion-input  #ref type="text" formControlName="x"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
```

**TS**

```
 @ViewChild('ref') ref:Elementef;

 onFocus(){      
   //set autofocus when click the button
     this.ref['_native'].nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Other wise use autofocus attribute

```
<ion-input autofocus="true" name="title"></ion-input>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ewuvzq

Comment: The stackblitz doesn't work. Both suggestions tried and they're not working

Comment: it is working check properly. if you click the button it will autometically focus input element

Comment: What I meant is that the stackblitz is not loading. It's showing "Starting dev server" forever.

Comment: try to open in some other browser

Comment: Ok, the stackblitz works now. However have a different use case. I have a list of inputs. And I have a button that adds an item to my model. The newly added item results in another list item - and that is the item that I have to focus. See this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bcm84s?file=pages/home/home.html

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the autofocus native attribute, just like this.

```
<ion-input autofocus="true" name="title"></ion-input>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. I created the directive to be able to bind the focus. When binding to [autofocus], the focus is lost or not there.